# How to check username and password from server database and display a new page in iPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I have an application in which I have a login form which consist of username and password. When user enters username and password his username and password should be validated from the server API database and if he is a valid user he should be made to login.

I have done the following code to post the login information through server API database:

```
 -(void)sendRequest
    {
        
        UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
        NSString *udid = [device uniqueIdentifier];
        NSString *sysname = [device systemName];
        NSString *sysver = [device systemVersion];
        NSString *model = [device model];
        NSLog(@"idis:%@",[device uniqueIdentifier]);
        NSLog(@"system nameis :%@",[device systemName]);
        NSLog(@"System version is:%@",[device systemVersion]);
        NSLog(@"System model is:%@",[device model]);
        NSLog(@"device orientation is:%d",[device orientation]);
        NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Loginkey=%@&Password=%@&DeviceCode=%@&Firmware=%@&IMEI=%@",txtUserName.text,txtPassword.text,model,sysver,udid];
        NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]; 
        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]]; 
        NSLog(@"%@",postLength);
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease]; 
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.0.68:91/JourneyMapperAPI?RequestType=Login"]]; 
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"]; 
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"]; 
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"]; 
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];
        
        NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        
        if (theConnection) {
            webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
            NSLog(@"%@",webData);
        }
        else 
        {
            
        }
        
    }
```

In this method I am parsing the JSON response received from API server and binding and inserting into SQLite database:

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
    {      
        NSString *loginStatus = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] length:[webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
        NSLog(@"%@",loginStatus); 
            
        NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:webData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
        
        NSDictionary *result = [json_string JSONValue];
        NSArray *values = [result objectForKey:@"Result"];
        NSMutableArray *results = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        
        for (int index = 0; index<[values count]; index++) {
            NSMutableDictionary * value = [values objectAtIndex:index];
            Result * result = [[Result alloc] init];
            result.UserID = [value objectForKey:@"UserId"];
            result.FirstName = [value objectForKey:@"FirstName"];
            result.LastName =[value objectForKey:@"LastName"];
            result.Email =[value objectForKey:@"Email"];
            result.ProfileImage =[value objectForKey:@"ProfileImage"];
            result.ThumbnailImage =[value objectForKey:@"ThumbnailImage"];
            result.DeviceInfoId =[value objectForKey:@"DeviceInfoId"];
            NSLog(@"%@",result.UserID);
            
            
            [results addObject:result];
            [result release]; 
        }
        
        
        
        for (int index = 0; index<[results count]; index++) {
            Result * result = [results objectAtIndex:index];
            //save the object variables to database here
            
            
            [self createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded];
            
            NSString *filePath = [self getWritableDBPath];
            
            sqlite3 *database;
            NSTimeInterval timeStamp = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]; 
            NSNumber *timeStampObj = [NSNumber numberWithInt: timeStamp];
            NSLog(@"%@",timeStampObj);
            NSString *journeyid = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%@_%@", result.UserID, result.DeviceInfoId, timeStampObj];
            if(sqlite3_open([filePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
                const char *sqlStatement = "insert into UserInformation(journeyid,UserID,DeviceId,Username,Password,FirstName,Email) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
                if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)    {
                    sqlite3_bind_text( compiledStatement, 1, [journeyid UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                    sqlite3_bind_text( compiledStatement, 2, [result.UserID UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                    sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 3, [result.DeviceInfoId UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                    sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 4, [txtUserName.text UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                    sqlite3_bind_text(compiledStatement, 5, [txtPassword.text UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                    sqlite3_bind_text (compiledStatement, 6, [result.FirstName UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                    sqlite3_bind_text (compiledStatement, 7, [result.Email UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                    
                }
                if(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) != SQLITE_DONE ) {
                    NSLog( @"Save Error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database) );
                }
                else {
                    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"UIAlertView" message:@"Record added" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                    [alert show];
                    [alert release];
                    alert = nil;
                }
                
                sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
            }
            sqlite3_close(database);    
        }
        [loginStatus release];           
        [connection release];  
        [webData release]; 
    }
```

The problem is I want when a user enters their username and password the username and password should be validated from the server database and if the user is valid they should be allowed to login.

Comment: What problem you are facing in this code?

Comment: If the user is valid or not, the messages should be returned by the server in the JSON or the dictionary you create from JSON. Can you tell us what the server returns in case of invalid user?

Comment: Hi @iAmitWagh , i am not facing any problem in this code.Actually in this code i am posting to login information to my api server and saving into my sqlite database but actually i want that when user enters in username and password fields ,username and password should be directly validated from my api server database and not from sqlite database.Thanks

Comment: Hi @WTP , i am not facing any problem in this code.Actually in this code i am posting to login information to my api server and saving into my sqlite database but actually i want that when user enters in username and password fields ,username and password should be directly validated from my api server database and not from sqlite database.Thanks

Comment: you should change API such that it can return whether user is valid or not in response.

Comment: Hi @iAmitWagh, should i do different code for that

Comment: @rani Y cant u try my suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your JSON response, Use some other key to send the response for login success/Fail. Check using the

```
NSString *loginres=[result valueForKey:@"LoginResponse"];
```

Then validate using

```
if([loginres isEqualToString:@"Success"]
{
  //Valid user
}
else
{
  //InValid user
}
```

**OR**

If the authentication fail let the   `NSArray *values = [result objectForKey:@"Result"];` be NULL

Then check

```
if(values!=NULL)
{
      //Valid user
}
else
{
      //InValid user
}
```

Comment: Hi @KingofBliss, i tried your code but their is a problem .When i enter wrong username and password then too it shows that it is a valid user

Comment: Then problem with your websrvice. Please change it

Comment: Could you please tell me where is the problem. i have tried u r code like this  
 NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:webData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
 
 NSDictionary *result = [json_string JSONValue];
 NSArray *values = [result objectForKey:@"Result"];
 if(values!=NULL)
 {
  NSLog(@"Valid User");
 }
 else
 {
  NSLog(@"Invalid User");
 }

Comment: Hi @kingofBliss, i am confused now what to change .Which JSON response to change